# How to convert letters to UpperCase without uc() function?

Tags: perl, uppercase, lowercase

I'm trying to write a script which will convert all letters from lowercase to uppercase without using the `uc()` function.

Comment: Does it need to work with Unicode?

Comment: Why would you want to do that in the first place?

Comment: What's wrong with `uc` that it needs to be avoided?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use something like `$str =~ tr/a-z/A-Z/`, but `uc` is probably better for Unicode support, if it matters to you.

Comment: This is also working good, thanks

Answer (score 5):

Using regular expressions:

```
$str =~ s/(.)/\u$1/g;
```

Comment: `\u` is titlecase, `\U` is uppercase (`uc()`).

Comment: `\u` is "uppercase the next character" and the substitution is run for each character.

Comment: Note that this is just `uc` in disguise.